# TortoiseSVN login fails - malformed XML: no element found

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I support developers and we are having TortoiseSVN issues. When I browse to the repo like https://svn.domain.com/admin with admin being the repository name it takes a long time then presents login page, I login and it then fails with 'the XML response contains invalid XML, Malformed XML: no element found'. In the VisualSVN Server (v3.4.2) event log I get 'File does not exist: c:/program Files/VisualSVNServer/htdocs/admin' . Tried trailing slash, not putting the repository at the end, no go.

We have a certificate in place and I wrestled with that for a while but finally got group policy to deploy the certs and config to each machine.

Done 3 hours of searching (Google) and not much luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The URL `https://svn.domain.com/admin` does not lead to a repository. You should copy the correct URL either from VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console or via the web interface.

Read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/) for the detailed steps.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i have fix this issue using de option "Steal lock" ( checkbox in bottom left area of the form when you are setting a lock to repository files )
this error is causaded beacause some files it seems to be unlocked but really it isn't ( verify this from de Explorer window clicking the properties of the file, and then, SVN Properties.... then you can see the real state of the file )[Lock the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9ylG.png)